# Plotting PSNR vs BITRATE

Tags: python, matlab, computer-vision, compression, bitrate

I wonder if there is any available code in python or MATLAB in order to plot the psnr Vs Bitrate diagram ?
I've found a lot of questions published on the internet but none of them try to explain the process of this job

Comment: Hi, this question is too vague. Do you have the data to plot? Couldn't you just use `plot(psnr, bitrate)` in MATLAB or python? What is it that you are struggling with exactly, *collecting data, understanding what plotting psnr vs bitrate means, actually plotting the data...* Please add more detail so others can help you.

Comment: Yes hello, thanks for responding me. Actually I do have an original image with which I want to plot this graph ( this image can be coded by jpeg,jpeg2000,bpg and proposed method) the problem is that I don't understand exactly the process in order to do this graph.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to compare the [bitrate (aka. bits-per-pixel, bpp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677552/how-to-specify-bitrate-for-jpeg-compression) vs the [peak signal-to-noise ratio (PSNR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio) for images.

This can be done simply by starting with some reference image, then create many copies of this reference image with different levels of compression (different bitrate/bpp).

[Calculate and note the different bitrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305101/jpg-bits-per-pixel) for each copy of the image.

`bpp = (Size of image in bits) / (number of pixels in image)`

Then compare each copy of the image with the original reference image, to get the PSNR.

In MATLAB, this can be done with [the `psnr()` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/psnr.html) (this requires the MATLAB Image Processing Toolbox.) The syntax for MATLAB is `[peak_snr, snr] = psnr( copy_image, original_image )`

In python, one option is [with OpenCV's PSNR function.](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga3119e3ea73010a6f810bb05aa36ac8d6) The syntax for OpenCV [is `cv2.psnr(img1, img2)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253688/incorrect-results-for-psnr-calculation)

Then, once you have the corresponding bitrates-psnr values, you can plot it and be done.